# Shared library not found

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I am running Ubuntu 10.10 and a C program that uses a shared library libcrypto.so
When compiling it, though I have a Makefile that has the option -lcrypto, I get this message:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ./libcrypto.so when searching for -lcrypto
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
```

I did export the current directory before by doing:

<s>`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=D_LIBRARY_PATH:.`</s>

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.
```

So what is wrong with my library and what can I do?

Comment: Shouldn't this be export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error message probably indicates that you have a 64-bit library but are doing a 32-bit compilation, or a 32-bit library but are doing a 64-bit compilation.

Run `file libcrypto.so` to see what type it is, then adjust your build (restart - remove all the object files) with either the option '`-m32`' or '`-m64`' to get the write build mode.  If you can't work out how else to get that into the `makefile`, use:

```
make CC="gcc -m32" CXX="g++ -m32"
```

(or the 64-bit version if that's what you're after).

Comment: you are right, libcrypto is 32-bit library, while i am running in 64-bit ubuntu. you are telling me in Makefile to put: gcc -m32 -lrt ......  ; anyway i am getting this message: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory

Comment: @Madrugada: I don't know what the missing header means - have you ever tried a 32-bit compilation before, and if so, does it work?  The message might be indicating that you need to reconfigure your software, or it might be telling you that your system is not set up to do 32-bit builds, or ...  It may be easier simply to get a 64-bit version of `libcrypto.so`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you post the output of this:

```
$ file ./libcrypto.so
```

And check that it is the right version for your machine? (I.e. 32 vs 64 bit, etc?)